# MySQL: JSON_EXTRACT object from array where 2 conditions are true

Tags: mysql, json-extract

I have a `JSON` column that stores an array of `objects`, each `object` having 2 properties:

```
[
    {
        "title" : "CALCULATED",
        "applies" : true
    },
    {
        "title" : "APPROVED",
        "applies" : false
    },
    {
        "title" : "RECIEVED",
        "applies" : false
    },
]
```

I want to `SELECT` all records where one of the `objects` matches a specific `title` and `applies` equals `true`.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT 
    col 
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    JSON_EXTRACT(col, '$[*].title') = "APPROVED" AND 
    JSON_EXTRACT(col, '$[*].applies');
```

This returns all records that have an `object` with `title = "APROVED"` and `applies = true`, but independent of each other. In the array I wrote as an example, it would return true because there is an `object` with `title = "APPROVED"` and there is another `object` with `applies = true`. I want to get all records where both are true on the same object.

Comment: Could you edit your question and share the expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert JSON array column to rows using [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) then apply your condition in where clause :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
JOIN  JSON_TABLE(
         col,
         "$[*]"
         COLUMNS(
           title varchar(20) PATH "$.title",
           applies boolean PATH "$.applies"
         )
       ) data
 where title = 'APPROVED' and applies;
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ckoV9QtsgqA4hCw8tYnn7/0)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get data with `title` = "APROVED" and `applies` = true, you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(col, '{"title": "APPROVED", "applies": true}', '$');
```

I have create https://dbfiddle.uk/hrM80a8c .
Please check